# Maven: Install only the changed file

Tags: java, maven

Every time that I make a change on a file I will need to use `mvn install` in order to create the final `FAT JAR`.

However, since a very large number of `dependencies` is used in my `project`,
it takes too much time in order to to the `compilation and the packaging`.

**Is there any way to speed up this procedure?**

For example to add the new *.class* file on the JAR.

Comment: What exactly is the use case here?

Comment: I need to do the maven package faster since it requires ~5 minutes even if I just add a println.

Comment: I just wanted to know what the use case is in order to see if you may not need to do the package.

Ok, packaging the fat jar takes time, but in your development activities you can avoid that, and package only when you need to deploy.

What command exactly are you using to package?

Comment: Do you have a single module or a multi module build?

Comment: @Milan mvn install

Comment: Are your dependencies stable?

Comment: Almost all of them are from maven central. 3 of them are on the local repository.

Comment: Can you try restarting your computer and start build 2 times to check the if the second time building download the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a maven compile, only if you wish to check for compile errors. To create a jar, use mvn package instead of install. And disable copying of dependencies to the target folder.